# Why is model.read_attribute returning nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-activerecord, rspec-rails

**Note**: This situation is only happening in my rspec spec.

My understanding is that `model.read_attribute(:attr_name)` [returns a typecasted attribute value](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/read_attribute). Which means if `attr_name` belongs to a integer column, `read_attribute(:attr_name)` will return me a Fixnum.

But...

`model.read_attribute(:attr_name)` returns a `nil`

`model.attr_name` returns a non-nil `Fixnum` value

Rails version: 4.0.3

Comment: Not enough information. Perhaps the column contains really a `nil` value? Or you did not provide a valid parameter the method, what is unclear from your description? When you want to read the value that is returned by a method `model.foo`, you must call `model.read_attribute(:foo)` (note the `Symbol`).

Comment: @spickermann yup, I'm aware about the symbol. i made some edits to my question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: is it possible that you are using a factory that creates an incomplete record or `mock` something?

Comment: @spickermann I think the symbol is not needed, because read_attribute does a `name = attr_name.to_s` ( http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read/read_attribute )

Comment: @xlembouras But when I do a model.attr_name, it returns a non-nil value. Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by 'incomplete record'.

Comment: @xlembouras: You can also use a `String`. But in the original version of your question you used a unassigned variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR version**

My code expected the default value of `attr_name` to be at least `0`, but due to certain circumstances, the default value of the `attr_name` column in the database table was null. Which resulted in the error I mentioned above.

**Detailed explaination**

The schema of my development database was out of sync with my production database (due to a few migrations that did not went into production). So whenever I ran a `rake db:migrate`, it created a `schema.rb` based on out-of-sync development database's schema. And this schema was then used by `rake db:test:prepare`, creating a database based on the outdated schema. Most importantly, the code had expected the value of `attr_name` to be at least 0 value from `attr_name`, but in the outdated schema, the `attr_name` column was null by default.